# Arduino101 'freezes' when shaking it

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm seeing a randomly strange behaviour of the Arduino101. If I don't move the board everything works fine, but when I start shaking and moving constantly the board it randomly gets stuck. This means that you can not see anymore the BLE Arduino device when scanning, and the only way to work again with it it's to restart the board. When facing this issue, the power on the arduino is still ok. Again I repeat, it seems something related with shaking the board for a while.

Here's my sketch, hoping that you can help me understand the possible reasons for that (maybe some problem about performance or the way I handle interrupts).

```
#include "CurieIMU.h"
#include "CurieBLE.h"
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */

bool motion;
int aix, aiy, aiz;    // raw accelerometer values
int gix, giy, giz;    // raw gyro values

BLEPeripheral blePeripheral;
BLEService sensorService("19B10010-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214");
BLEUnsignedLongCharacteristic stepCharacteristic("19B10011-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead);  // stepcount
BLEFloatCharacteristic axCharacteristic("19B10012-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify); // acc.in x in g
BLEFloatCharacteristic ayCharacteristic("19B10013-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify); // acc.in y in g
BLEFloatCharacteristic azCharacteristic("19B10014-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify); // acc.in z in g
BLEFloatCharacteristic gxCharacteristic("19B10015-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify); // rot.in x in deg/s
BLEFloatCharacteristic gyCharacteristic("19B10016-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify); // rot.in y in deg/s
BLEFloatCharacteristic gzCharacteristic("19B10017-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify); // rot.in z in deg/s
BLEIntCharacteristic shockCharacteristic("19B10018-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLENotify);  // true if shock sensed
BLEIntCharacteristic modeCharacteristic("19B10019-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);  // sensing mode
BLEIntCharacteristic srangeCharacteristic("19B10020-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);  // shock range
BLEIntCharacteristic arangeCharacteristic("19B10021-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);  // acc. range
BLEIntCharacteristic grangeCharacteristic("19B100122-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite); // gyro range
BLEIntCharacteristic calibCharacteristic("19B100123-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);  // 1 if calibration is on, otherwise 0


void setup()
{

    CurieIMU.begin();
    blePeripheral.setLocalName("MOOVBIT");
    blePeripheral.setAdvertisedServiceUuid(sensorService.uuid());
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(sensorService);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(stepCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(axCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(ayCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(azCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(gxCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(gyCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(gzCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(shockCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(modeCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(arangeCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(srangeCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(grangeCharacteristic);
    blePeripheral.addAttribute(calibCharacteristic);
    // set initial characteristics values
    stepCharacteristic.setValue(0);
    shockCharacteristic.setValue(0);
    modeCharacteristic.setValue(0);
    arangeCharacteristic.setValue(4);
    srangeCharacteristic.setValue(4);
    grangeCharacteristic.setValue(250);
    calibCharacteristic.setValue(1);
    initPeriph();

    CurieIMU.setAccelerometerRange(arangeCharacteristic.value());
    CurieIMU.setGyroRange(grangeCharacteristic.value());
    CurieIMU.setStepDetectionMode(CURIE_IMU_STEP_MODE_SENSITIVE);
    CurieIMU.setStepCountEnabled(true);

    CurieIMU.setDetectionThreshold(CURIE_IMU_SHOCK, srangeCharacteristic.value() * 500); // 1g = 1000 mg
    CurieIMU.setDetectionDuration(CURIE_IMU_SHOCK, 50); // 50ms or 75ms
    CurieIMU.interrupts(CURIE_IMU_SHOCK);
    CurieIMU.interrupts(CURIE_IMU_MOTION);
    CurieIMU.attachInterrupt(eventCallback);
    motion = false;

}

void loop()
{
    if (motion) {
        if (!axCharacteristic.setValue(convertRawAcceleration(aix)) || !ayCharacteristic.setValue(convertRawAcceleration(aiy)) ||
            !azCharacteristic.setValue(convertRawAcceleration(aiz)) || !gxCharacteristic.setValue(convertRawGyro(gix)) ||
            !gyCharacteristic.setValue(convertRawGyro(giy)) || !gzCharacteristic.setValue(convertRawGyro(giz))) {
            //Serial.println("Erorr BLE");
        }
        stepCharacteristic.setValue(CurieIMU.getStepCount());
        motion = false;
    }
    delay(2000);
    shockCharacteristic.setValue(0);
}

void eventCallback() {
    if (CurieIMU.getInterruptStatus(CURIE_IMU_SHOCK)) {
        if (shockCharacteristic.value() == 0) {
            //Serial.println("Shock sensed");
            shockCharacteristic.setValue(1);
        }
        //CurieIMU.readMotionSensor(aix, aiy, aiz, gix, giy, giz);
        //motion = true;
    }
    else if (CurieIMU.getInterruptStatus(CURIE_IMU_MOTION)) {
        CurieIMU.readMotionSensor(aix, aiy, aiz, gix, giy, giz);
        motion = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to simplify the code, part by part, until it doesn't "freeze" anymore. Then you have hopefully been able to pinpoint what part of the code causes the freezing, and should be able to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, if you still can't figure it out yourself.

Comment: I simplified my code now

Comment: Sounds like a wire problem. Maybe something coming lose...